# ajax email pass spring mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, email, spring-mvc

How to pass email id via ajax call (not as string), i need to catch that email parameter in spring controller.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        data: data,
        dataType: "text",
        url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/methodName";,
        success : function(data){

        }
        });
```

Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/methodName/{email}", method =RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String resetPassword(@PathVariable(value = "email") String email) throws Exception{
        //do something
        return "success";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code did the trick.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data: { 
            'email': email
        },
        url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/methodName";,
        success : function(data){

        }
        });

@RequestMapping(value="/methodName", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String resetPassword(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email) throws Exception{
        //do something
        return "success";
    }
```